# WS2812B - flickering and artifacts

Tags: led, rgb

I have a project that has 48 various lengths of WS2812B RGB tape strips. All 12V.

Here is a link to the tape i am using. [datasheet](https://www.enttec.com/products/lights/led-tapes/pixet-tape-rgb60-12/)

I seem to have a lot of flickering at the ends and the occasional flash or artifact when running animations.

I am not sure what the issue is, i cant tell if it is voltage or signal. What can i do to determine where the problem is?

Does this sound like common issues with this tape?
Thanks,

Comment: Dont cascade them all.  Stick to one 5m and then feed in parallel or use dual power injection for 9m

Comment: Power should be injected ever few metres.

Comment: None of my strips are over 4.2M and I have 8 of them on a 600w power supply (HLG-600) all run parallel. Total watts used per power supply is 455watts per PS.

Comment: The voltage is too low at the end of the strip.

Comment: Have you connected the ground of the Arduino/Micro-controller to the ground of power supply ?. I had the same flickering issue when i forgot to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed. I had a similar flickering issue with 5V addressable LEDs with about 2.5-3 meters of cable. Even if the all connections were insulated, holding the LED strip in my hand provided a lot of capacity through the ground connection to eliminate the RF noise. So adding one simple ferrite clamp solved this issue instantly.

Answer (score 1):

Is the supply with specs at middle, ends and have you not exceeded the Run length table?.

If V+ is in spec, you may be getting interference on data lines from something.  Any clues?

If you have a ferrite clamp to put around cable,or you can earth ground the source (laptop? or supply) , this will help greatly reduce CM noise interference, which is a common problem for high speed Serial data on long cables with high impedance.

Ensure data ground and supply ground are well connected.

Comment: I have the supply at one end, but I dont know if I exceed the run length. The manufacturer does not have a table, is there a standard one on line somewhere?  I could be getting interference, but i am not sure what to do about it or how to confirm that I am.  What would the results look like if I were out of spec on the voltage?

Comment: your link has the datasheet with run length limits. How long is it? what colour?

Comment: None are longer than 4.2 meters and they are RGB